# ease off followed by a gerund or an infinitive

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

> I eased off studying English.

or

> I eased off to study English.

I think 2 is wrong but 1 is possible.

Answer (score 2):

1 *I eased off studying.*
is correct to say that you studied less.

2 *I eased off to study.*
is also possible if *to study* expresses purpose, for example,

*Why aren't you playing tennis today?*
*I eased off [playing tennis] to study [chemistry].*

Comment: Yes: 2. I eased off _in order_ to study. A purpose adjunct